# Using `split` inside array and vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays, split

The below code produces this:

[image: output]

I want to get that second line top-aligned, so the `$\frac{\partial^2g}{(\partial n^1_\mu)^2}$` and `$\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n^1_\sigma)^2}$` are on the same level. How can I accomplish this?

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\xm}{\overline{\mathbf{x}}}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{20pt}
\[
\begin{array}{l r}
\displaystyle
\frac{\partial g}{\partial n_\mu^1} = \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1}
&
\displaystyle
\frac{\partial g}{\partial n^1_\sigma} = \partial_1f(\xm) \cdot \left( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \right)
\\[20pt]
\displaystyle
\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n^1_\mu)^2} = \partial^2_1f(\xm)\left( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \right)^2
&
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n_\sigma^1)^2} = \partial_1 f(\xm) \cdot 2 \left( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^3} \right)
\\
{} + \partial_1^2 f(\xm)\left( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \right)^2
\end{split}
\\[20pt]
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial n_\mu^1 \partial n_\sigma^1} = \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2}
\\
{} + \partial_1^2 f(\xm) \left( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \right)
\\
{} \cdot \left( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \right)
\end{split}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `aligned` with option `[t]`, not `split`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest using an `alignat*` environment in the place of `array` as you can have full control on the spacing between columns. I replaced  `split` with `aligned`, which can take an optional argument for the vertical placement: `t, c` (the default) and `b`.

Also, I loaded `esdiff` to have a simplified typing of partial derivatives, and used the `\widebar` command from `mathabx` (without loading all the mathabx fonts), as I think it looks nicer than `\overline`. Finally the `mleftright` package gives a better spacing for large delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, mleftright}
\usepackage{esdiff} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}
\newcommand{\xm}{\widebar{\mathbf{x}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\diffp{ g}{{n_\mu^1}} & = \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1}
&
\diffp{g}{{n^1_\sigma}} & = \partial_1f(\xm) \cdot \mleft( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \mright)
\\[1ex]
\diffp[2]{g}{(n^1_\mu\smash{)}}
& = \partial^2_1f(\xm)\left( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \right)^2
&
\diffp[2]{g}{(n_\sigma^1\smash{)}} & = \begin{aligned}[t] & \partial_1 f(\xm) \cdot 2 \mleft( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^3} \mright)
\\
\mathllap{{} +{}} & \partial_1^2 f(\xm)\mleft( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \mright)^{\mkern-5mu 2}
\end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
\diffp{g}{{n_\mu^1}{n_\sigma^1}} & =
\begin{aligned}[t] & \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \\
\mathllap{{} + {}}& \partial_1^2 f(\xm) \left( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \right)
\\
\mathllap{{} \cdot} &\mleft( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \mright)
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're lucky enough that the last equation (unsplit) is as wide as the top line. So I suggest to `gather` everything, with the first two pairs `aligned` (with a nested `aligned` for splitting the fourth equation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xm}{\overline{\mathbf{x}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial n_\mu^1}
&=\partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1}
&
\frac{\partial g}{\partial n^1_\sigma} 
&=\partial_1f(\xm) \cdot \biggl( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 
  - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \biggr)
\\[2ex]
\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n^1_\mu)^2}
&= \partial^2_1f(\xm)\biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \biggr)^{\!2}
&
\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n_\sigma^1)^2} 
&= \begin{aligned}[t]
   &\partial_1 f(\xm) \cdot 2 \biggl( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 - 
     \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^3} \biggr)
   \\
   &\quad + \partial_1^2 f(\xm)\biggl( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 -
    \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \biggr)^{\!2}
   \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial n_\mu^1 \partial n_\sigma^1} 
= \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2}
  + \partial_1^2 f(\xm) \biggl( -\gamma_1 \frac{x_1 -
    \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \biggr)
   \cdot \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \biggr)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

yet another way of looking at this.  the second equaton on the second line will
fit within the text width, so why not keep it on one line by itself?  then a
simple `align*` can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xm}{\overline{\mathbf{x}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial n_\mu^1}
&= \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1}
 \qquad\qquad
 \frac{\partial g}{\partial n^1_\sigma} 
  =\partial_1f(\xm) \cdot \biggl( -\gamma_1
     \frac{x_1  - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \biggr)\\[2\jot]
\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n^1_\mu)^2}
&= \partial^2_1f(\xm)\biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \biggr)^{\!2}\\[2\jot]
\frac{\partial^2 g}{(\partial n_\sigma^1)^2} 
&= \partial_1 f(\xm) \cdot 2 \biggl( -\gamma_1
     \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^3} \biggr)
  + \partial_1^2 f(\xm)\biggl( -\gamma_1
     \frac{x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \biggr)^{\!2}
\\[2\jot]
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial n_\mu^1 \partial n_\sigma^1} 
&= \partial_1f(\xm)\cdot \frac{-\gamma_1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2}
  + \partial_1^2 f(\xm) \biggl( -\gamma_1
    \frac{x_1 -  \mu_1 - n_\mu^1}{(\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1)^2} \biggr)
  \cdot \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1 + n_\sigma^1} \biggr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

this applies fixed sizing to the parentheses (`\bigg` is usually a good choice for fractions of this sort). it also uses a multiple of the dimension `\jot` to specify the line separation; `1\jot` is the default separation for `align`, and
actually, with the equations laid out like this, extra separation isn't really
needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach. One can avoide line breaks inside the subformulas entirely, by replacing the repeated elements `\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1` and `x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1` with, say, `\xi` and `\phi`. Then, use an `array` environment to typeset the five subformulas across just 3 instead of 6 lines.

Do try to keep the sizes of the large parentheses consistent; I suggest using `\Bigl(` and `Bigr(` throughout.

As @Bernard did in his answer, I suggest loading the `esdiff` package and using the `\diffp` macro to streamline the typesetting of the partial-differential terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esdiff} % for \diffp macro

\usepackage{array}  % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % automatic display-style math mode
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for columns with "=" symbols

\newcommand{\xm}{\bar{\mathbf{x}}}

\begin{document}

Put $\xi=\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1$ and $\phi=x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1$. Then 
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{RCL @{\qquad} RCL}
  \diffp{g}{{n_\mu^1}} 
  &=& \partial_1f(\xm) \Bigl(\frac{-\gamma^{}_1}{\xi} \Bigr)
  & \diffp{g}{{n^1_\sigma}} 
  &=& \partial_1f(\xm) \Bigl( \frac{-\gamma^{}_1\phi}{\xi^2} \Bigr)
\\[3ex]
  \diffp[2]{g}{(n^1_\mu)}
  &=& \partial^2_1f(\xm)\Bigl( \frac{-\gamma^{}_1}{\xi} \Bigr)^{\!2}
  & \diffp[2]{g}{(n_\sigma^1)} 
  &=& \partial_1 f(\xm) \cdot 2 \Bigl( \frac{-\gamma^{}_1\phi}{\xi^3} \Bigr)
    + \partial_1^2 f(\xm) \Bigl( \frac{-\gamma^{}_1 \phi}{\xi^2} \Bigr)^{\!2} 
\\[3ex]
  \diffp{g}{{n_\mu^1}{n_\sigma^1}} 
  &=& \multicolumn{4}{L}{%
      \partial_1f(\xm) \frac{-\gamma^{}_1}{\xi^2} 
    + \partial_1^2 f(\xm) \Bigl( \frac{-\gamma^{}_1\phi}{\xi^2} \Bigr)
      \Bigl( \frac{-\gamma^{}_1}{\xi} \Bigr)}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If using abbreviation terms such as `\xi` and `\phi` isn't suitable, I'd like to suggest displaying the five partial-derivative expressions across five separate lines. That way, the reader's eye doesn't have to "hunt" across lines to take in the expression for each partial derivative. And, five rows is still one row less than in your original solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align* environment
\usepackage{esdiff}  % for \diffp macro
\usepackage{kpfonts} % Palatino clone
\newcommand{\xm}{\bar{\mathbf{x}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\diffp{g}{{n_\mu^1}} 
  &= \partial_1 f(\xm) \biggl(\frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1} \biggr) 
\\
\diffp{g}{{n^1_\sigma}} 
  &= \partial_1 f(\xm) \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1(x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1)}{(\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1)^2} \biggr)
\\
\diffp[2]{g}{(n^1_\mu)}
  &= \partial^2_1f(\xm)\biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1} \biggr)^{\!2} 
\\
\diffp[2]{g}{(n_\sigma^1)} 
  &= \partial_1 f(\xm) \cdot 2 \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1(x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1)}{(\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1)^3} \biggr)
    +\partial_1^2 f(\xm) \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1 (x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1)}{(\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1)^2} \biggr)^{\!2} 
\\
\diffp{g}{{n_\mu^1}{n_\sigma^1}} 
  &= \partial_1f(\xm) \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{(\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1)^2} \biggr)
    +\partial_1^2 f(\xm) \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1(x_1 - \mu_1 - n_\mu^1)}{(\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1)^2} \biggr)
     \biggl( \frac{-\gamma_1}{\sigma_1+n_{\sigma}^1} \biggr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```